# Circle Button with visible radius and Image as a child

Tags: user-interface, flutter

Goal: Implementing perfect sized *Circle Button* with visible radius and Image as a child

---

Screenshot to demonstrate:
[image: Left:Design to implement,Right: Tried Solutions]

As you can see from the above picture, I tried many solutions that are mentioned here by the community here

Including:

1. **CircleAvatar**

```
    CircleAvatar(
     child: Image.asset('assets/images/gucci.jpg')
    )
```

---

2. **ClipRRect**

```
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      child: Image.asset(
         'assets/images/gucci.jpg',
         height: 100.0,
         width: 100.0,
      )
    )
```

---

3. **Material** widget with **Ink.image** as a child widget

```
Material(
   elevation: 1.0,
   shape: CircleBorder(),
   clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
   color: Colors.transparent,
   child: Ink.image(
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/gucci.jpg'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: 120.0,
      height: 120.0,
      child: InkWell(
         onTap: () {},
      )
   )
)
```

---

Any ideas on how to implement this design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of options for you. One of them is 'FloatingActionButton'.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 60,
  height: 60,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      shape: CircleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 1,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/gucci.jpg'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I would prefer it over `Container` since all the button's attributes like `onPressed` or tap animation are already implemented in `FloatingActionButton` and you don't need to use `GestureDetector` or `InkWell`.

Also you can use `CircleBorder` in any other `Button`s or `Widget`s which accept a `ShapeBorder`.

Comment: This actually works, thank you, but there's a catch. using multiple fabs on the same screen is discouraged by Material Design guidelines (https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html), "Don't display multiple FABs on a single screen." let alone using 5 or 10 of them on the same screen,  the other thing is that there's no control over the size of the fab itself, so it would be very small on large screens and especially on the Web.

Comment: @Waleedsyr You are using `FloatingActionButton` only for its shape, not as a fab button. So it doesn't violate the material design rules... Also, I edited my answer to make the button size bigger...

Comment: it worked! , I just added a Padding widget around the Image so it would become centered, and here's the result (https://snipboard.io/ThBPqn.jpg). Thank you for your time

Comment: @Waleedsyr Happy to help mate. Have fun Fluttering

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want some padding and a border around the button.

```
SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Material(
          elevation: 1.0,
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            child: Ink.image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/gucci.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been looking for, there are two issues appeared though, the photo appears to be cut off on the corners (https://snipboard.io/7VpuAL.jpg) I tried to wrap the InkWell with Center widget, it didn't work. and there's a problem with the splash layout when invoking onPress(), the splash takes the shape of the SizedBox (Which is Rectangular) and not as a circle (https://snipboard.io/yWLcHm.jpg) , any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Container()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and [GestureDetector()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) for tap functionality, I guess this will do

**Code**

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: (){},
   child: Container(
     height: 120.0,
     width: 120.0,
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/gucci.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
        )
     )
   )
)
```

You can change the thickness of the border by playing with the `width` in `border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5)` and for `circular container`, make changes in this line `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),`. This will help.

Comment: This was the result (https://snipboard.io/jJltzA.jpg) Container appears as an ellipse rather than a circle, changing the width and height of the container didn't solve the problem,nor changing the borderRadius attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Container` with `Inkwell` or `GestureDetector`.

Here is sample code:

```
    InkWell(
           onTap: (){},
            child: Container(
              width: 65,
              height: 65,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/gucci.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.5)),
                border: new Border.all(
                 color: Colors.black,
                 width: 2.0,
               ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){},
            child: Container(
              width: 65,
              height: 65,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/gucci.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.5)),
                border: new Border.all(
                 color: Colors.black,
                 width: 2.0,
               ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Both samples are showing the Container as an oval, not as a circle (https://snipboard.io/LqMOl2.jpg), I  tried changing the width and height of the container but it didn't work